# Replacing words in a document

Tags: python

My goal is to write a function that takes two strings and two filenames. The function replaces the first string in the first file with the second string. After that, it writes the contents into the second file. This is what I did:

```
def sed(s1, s2, f1, f2):
    try:
        fin1 = open(f1,'r')
        fin2 = open(f2, 'w')
        for word in fin1:
            if word == s1:
                word = s2
                fin2.write(word)
            else:
                fin2.write(word)
    except:
        'something went wrong'
```

However, the replacing part didn't quite work. The first string did not get replaced with the second string. I know that there is a .replace built in Python, but I want to write my own replace function for practice.

Comment: `for word in fin1:` reads the file line by line, not word by word

Comment: How can I make it read word by word?

Comment: Instead of what you have, might I recommend `except Exception as e: sys.exit("Something when wrong: "+str(e))`.  This way you can actually see specifically what went wrong.  In practice, you should catch specific errors, like `OSError` or `IOError` so that other unexpected errors like `AttributeError` or `TypeError` don't mysteriously throw you on a wild goose chase.

Comment: Also, just putting the string `'something went wrong'` won't do anything.  You need `print` or `sys.exit`, depending on your intent.

Comment: Wrapping your code in an all-encompassing `try-except` block is generally a very bad idea (yes, there are ... ahem ... *exceptions* to that rule).

Comment: You need to clarify what you're really trying to do: perform a simple word-level replacement function; implement your own version of the build-in `str.replace` function; mimic the Unix sed command; or something else. If you provide example input values and desired results (show us example data), you might get more useful advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get word from lines use `str.split()`

```
for line in fin1:
    for word in line.split():
```

Comment: One problem with this is that it will split on white space by default and words will include trailing commas and full stops.

Comment: Also true, but it's still worth mentioning, for that very reason

Answer (score -1):

Not using the builtin methods for a task like this is not a good idea since you are complicating things a lot. I assume you don't want use the regular expressions operations module 're' either...So find my answer below. This could be written in less lines, but this way is more readable:

```
def replace_string(string1, string2, file1, file2):
  with open(file1, 'r') as first_file:
    my_lines = []
    for line in first_file.readlines():
      if string1 in line:
        for word in line.split(string1):
          if word != string1:
            if (word and '\n' not in word):
              new_word = word+string2
            else:
              new_word = word
          my_lines.append(new_word)
      else:
        my_lines.append(line)
  with open(file2, 'w') as second_file:
    for item in my_lines:
      second_file.write(item)
```

Let's say you have 'first_file.txt' that looks like this:

```
This is my first line. It contains the words: cat, dog, fish, cat.
This is the second line. cat. ‘cat’ is a pet
This is the third line. cat...cat cat.
You have hopefully replaced all occurrences of *cat*cat
```

And you want to replace string 'cat' with 'new_cat' and save it to a file 'second_file.txt'. You don't need to create the second_file.txt, it will just be created in the same location where you run the code.

```
replace_string('cat', 'new_cat', 'first_file.txt', 'second_file.txt')
```

Your second file will look like this:

```
This is my first line. It contains the words: new_cat, dog, fish, new_cat.
This is the second line. new_cat. ‘new_cat’ is a pet
This is the third line. new_cat...new_cat new_cat.
You have hopefully replaced all occurrences of *new_cat*new_cat
```

Of course, this is not perfect. What happens if you have a word in your file 'catcat'...Would you like to ignore it? Or you would like to turn it into 'new_catnew_cat'? This code will turn it into 'new_cat' only...So here comes another condition to check for and so on...